# Checking if e-mail exists but returning empty query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a bit of code that checks if an email exists in my table but keep receiving a "Query was empty" error. I can't seem  to find why the query is returning empty?

I am new to PHP and am following a tutorial online for this, the code to which I am following seems to be identical. My code:

recover1.php

```
<?php require_once('Connections/localhost.php'); ?>
<?php
  session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
    header("Location: My_Account.php");
    die;
}
?>

<?php include('functions2.php'); ?>

<?php
$mode_allowed = array('username', 'password');
if (isset($_GET['mode']) === true && in_array($_GET['mode'], $mode_allowed) == true) {
    if (isset($_POST['email']) === true && empty($_POST['email']) === false) {
        if (email_exists(($_POST['email'])) === true) {
        echo "ok";
        } else {
            echo '<div id="error"> We could not find that email address, please try again. </div>';
        }
    }
?>  

<?php   
} else {
    header('Location: subscribe.php');
    exit();

}
?>
```

functions2.php

```
    <?php

function sanitize($data) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data); 
}

function recover ($mode, $email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $mode = sanaitize($mode);
    $user_data = user_data(UserID_from_email($email), `Username`);
    if ($mode == 'username') {
        email($email, 'Your Username', "Hi/n As requested your username is " . $user_data['Username'] . "/n/n Infinity Crates");
    } else if ($mode == 'password') {
        //recover password
    }
}

function email_exists($email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`UserID`) FROM `users` WHERE `Email` = '$email'");
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    return (mysql_result($result, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function UserID_from_email($email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `UserID` from `Users` WHERE `Email` = '$email'"), 0, `UserID`); 
}

function email($to, $subject, $body) {
    mail($to, $subject, $body, 'From: infinitycrate@gmail.com');    
}

?>
```

Comment: First thing I noticed: `$mode = sanaitize($mode);` you misspelled sanitize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using mysql_query 2 times.

Make it:

```
function email_exists($email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $query = "SELECT COUNT (`UserID`) FROM `users` WHERE `Email` = '$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    return (mysql_result($result, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

You can even modify your function like this:

```
function email_exists($email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email` = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
    return (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Note: Default Mysql API is deprecated from PHP 5.5. Please use PDO and Mysqli instead. For more information you can take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0):

Your functions either need to globalize the mysql_connect resource variable or have the resource passed to the function. Check your first require_once file and see if the mysql_connect resource is stored in a variable. If not, modify it to save the resource to a variable like `$dbh` and modify the "email_exists", "sanitize" and "UserID_from_email" functions by inserting `global $dbh;` as the first line in those functions.

Comment: The mysql_connect is already assigned in that file, here: $localhost = mysql_pconnect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); I tried puttin global $localhost; in  but still have problem.